# How to re-recognize a USB webcam without rebooting Ubuntu?

Tags: webcam

Ubuntu may not recognize my USB webcam while logging in to Ubuntu.

Ubuntu does not re-recognize the USB webcam when I re-plug the USB webcam into the USB port on my computer.

How to re-recognize the USB webcam without rebooting Ubuntu?

Does anyone know of the command(line) to re-recognize a USB webcam without rebooting Ubuntu?

Comment: You will want to check the logs to see why Ubuntu does not want to recognise your webcam. `/var/log/syslog` will list every step of the process when first detecting a USB device, performing the handshake, and — if necessary — erroring out. If you can [edit] your question to include this information, the version of Ubuntu you're running, and the brand and model of USB webcam, it may be possible to offer a suggestion 

Comment: /var/log/syslog
was Today's log only...

Comment: Ubuntu Linux may not have plug-and-play recognized the USB webcam because pavucontrol was running.